# Virus signature extraction form malware

Tags: security, antivirus, virus, malware

I'm writing a simple antivirus in C.
I've got some malware samples and I want to extract signatures form them.
Any idea how to extract them?

Comment: What have you tried? Care to show some code? If you haven't tried anything you'll hardly get a good answer here, because people will assume you want them to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving a "signature" could be as simple as generating a digital signature via hashing for the virus(es) respective binaries. MD5 or SHA. 
I.E. implementing the following functionality in your code that I'm *sure* you've already started...:

`md5sum virus` -> *md5hashofvirus* |
`md5sum virus2` -> *md5hashofvirus2*

Complete dossier of md5sum available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum).

MD5 implementation in C available [here](http://openwall.info/wiki/people/solar/software/public-domain-source-code/md5).

However any modification to the file would render this method of detection useless (albeit that's the end goal of encrypting a virus). An actual "virus signature" that modern AV's use is

> "any sequence of bits that can be used to accurately identify the presence of a particular virus in a given file or range of memory."

As that level of analysis makes it a bit harder for malware manufacturers to hide the "identity" of the malware.

- www.agusblog.com/wordpress/what-is-a-virus-signature-are-they-still-used-3.htm is something that I feel you should read.
- www.labri.fr/perso/ly/publications/viro.pdf if you're looking for something a little more indepth.

If you'd like more information, try sharing a bit more yourself.